# Unable to scroll android native app with appium using java client 7.0

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I am unable to scroll the android app vertically with Appium. 
I am using the **java-client 7.0.0** API.
`Action.press` is not working

```
(new TouchAction(driver))
  .press({x: 600, y: 2408})
  .moveTo({x: 348: y: 615})
  .release()
  .perform()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following as an example:

```
/**
 * This method scrolls based upon the passed parameters
 * @author Bill Hileman
 * @param int startx - the starting x position
 * @param int starty - the starting y position
 * @param int endx - the ending x position
 * @param int endy - the ending y position
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void scroll(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy) {

    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);

    touchAction.longPress(PointOption.point(startx, starty))
               .moveTo(PointOption.point(endx, endy))
               .release()
               .perform();

}
```

Comment: Hi Bill Hileman, Thanks, for the solution It's working for me. I am trying to scroll the middle section of the app (except header and footer) using the same code. It's not working for that. Can you please provide the solution for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on your example, you're attempting to scroll from somewhere on the lower right of the screen to the upper left of the screen?  Usually vertical and horizontal scrolls keep either the x or the y coordinate the same and only change the other.  Are you meaning to do a diagonal swipe?  I generally get the screen dimensions and determine a percentage, i.e. for a horizontal scroll I pick the mid-point x and set y to 20% to 80%, follow?

Comment: Could you please mark it as the accepted answer?  Glad I could help, and thanks for letting me know.